# Generate transaction ID for POS

Tags: database, transactions, client-server

I don't exactly know how to describe this so I am having trouble googling the answer or finding it on this forum.

Basically I am working on a point of sale system. I have written a few of these but they have never been a server and multiple client design.

I was wondering how do POS systems generate the transaction ID's when there are simultaneous transactions and what happens to a cancelled transaction ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done POS stuff.

When you need the newest inserted row's primary key to use as transaction ID, return the @@identity value to use on the client side.

Cancelled transactions can either be rolled back if you've been doing all the work within a TRANSACTION block in SQL or a .NET transaction, but the easiest way that causes the least problems is really just having an isCancelled boolean field that gets set to true when the transaction is cancelled.

Comment: Thanx, I always wondered about how they do that. I program in Java and think I will use the isCancelled you mentioned but will have a look at the SQL transaction blocks you also just to find out a bit more

Answer (score 1):

Instead taxing the database for this ID generation, you might do this using a GUID.  Also, this allows for the possibility of your terminals functioning independently with cached data even when the network connection is severed (was a requirement for one of my projects).